# How can I convert image byte[] to String, then again []byte in Andorid

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, decode, encode

I get a image from gallery. name : filePath

```
 if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            filePath = data.getData();

          
            Bitmap ImgBitmap = null;

            
            ImgBitmap = resize(getApplicationContext(), filePath, 300);

            Byte_image = BitmapToByteArray(ImgBitmap);


            try {
                // Uri파일로 bitmap resize
                //resize(getApplicationContext(), filePath, 1000);

                // 이미지 암호화
                EncryptImg = aesCoderAndriod.encrypt(seed, Byte_image);

                String EncryptString = new String(EncryptImg,"UTF-8");

                Log.e("Encrypt", EncryptString);
                FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                            .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object");
                String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                    HashMap<Object,String> object = new HashMap<Object, String>();

                    object.put("title","image_title");
                    object.put("photo",EncryptString);

                    DatabaseReference keyRef = databaseReference.child(key);
                    keyRef.setValue(object);
```

filePath -> Bitmap -> byte[] -> String and save in the firebase realtimeDB.
Then, I call firebaseDB value "photo". I get "photo" value in En1.
En1(String) -> En2([]byte) -> Dn1(decrypted) -> Dn2(Bitmap)-> Dn3(Uri)

[image]

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object");
        
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        ItemObject itemObject = snapshot.getValue(ItemObject.class);

                        String title = itemObject.getTitle();
                        String En1 = itemObject.getPhoto();

                        Log.e("En1",En1);

                        byte[] En2 = En1.getBytes(UTF_8);


                        Log.e("En2", En2.toString());
                        try {
                            byte[] Dn1 = aesCoderAndriod.decrypt(seed, En2);
                            Bitmap Dn2 = byteArrayToBitmap(Dn1);
                            Uri Dn3 = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),Dn2);
                           
                            Log.e("Dn3", String.valueOf(Dn3));
                            
                            itemObject = new ItemObject(title, Dn3.toString());
                            mItem.add(itemObject);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //   itemObject.setPhoto(snapshot.child("Photo").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    // myAdapter= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mItem);
                    // mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

but, there is a problem with get []byte.

The value get from DB(En1) and the value converted to byte[] again(En2) are different.
What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: This isn't the right way to do it. Load as raw bytes and use Base64 encoding instead

Comment: @ControlAltDel <<EncryptImg = aesCoderAndriod.encrypt(seed, Byte_image);>> in here?

Comment: That looks about right. TBH I've never done this in Java but I've been doing it a lot in JavaScript where it works like a charm.